# extract-i18n --output-path extracts in root folder

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, xliff

For extracting translations I use i18n in combination with xliffmerge.
I have added the `extract-i18n` command in the `package.json` like so:

`"extract-i18n": "ng extract-i18n project --i18n-format xlf --output-path src/locale --i18n-locale en-US && ng run project:xliffmerge"`

The `xliffmergeOptions` in `angular.json` are:

```
"xliffmerge": {
          "builder": "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling:xliffmerge",
          "options": {
            "xliffmergeOptions": {
              "format": "xlf",
              "srcDir": "src/locale",
              "genDir": "src/locale",
              "defaultLanguage": "en-US",
              "languages": [
                "en-US",
                "nl-NL"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Whenever I run the `extract-i18n` command the messages.xlf file still gets exported to the root folder instead of src/locale.

I have no idea why it isn't exported to the src/locale folder.

**Update**

After upgrading from Angular 11 to Angular 12 this problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the mistake of running `ng extract-i18n` while configuring it in a script in package.json. Instead I should have used `npm run extract-i18n`.

This solves only a part of the problem though, since `--i18n-format` and `--18n-locale` are no longer supported (or so it seems).

The correct command should be:

`"extract-i18n": "ng extract-i18n [projectname] --format xlf --output-path src/locale && ng run [projectname]:xliffmerge"`

Due to Angular deprecating the keyword "id" in the schema on favor of "$id" I'm not sure how long xliffmerge will continue to work though, since development on ngx-i18nsupport has stopped a few years ago.

Comment: have you actually found an alternative or solution to the xliffmerge problem not supporting the change from id to $id ?

Answer (score 0):

---

### please use this command

---

*extract-i18n --output-path src/locale*

*you are not define the path that's why you face the problems  you must define the path where generate the xml file now a days i am also working i18n if you have any query about i18n let me know i will help you.*

---

---

Comment: --output-path src/local already is in the i18n-extract command

Comment: some thing went wrong in your path directory

Comment: Do you have any idea where it may go wrong in the path directory?
What kind of code snippet do you want?

Comment: did use this command extract-i18n --output-path src/locale or not

Comment: "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "extract": "ng xi18n --output-path= src/locale",
    "start-dev": "webpack-dev-server — mode development — open",
    "start:hi": "npm start -- --configuration=hi  --base-href /hi/ --port=4202",
    "start:gu": "npm start -- --configuration=gu --base-href /gu/",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },

Comment: i use this command in angular.json   "extract": "ng xi18n --output-path= src/locale",

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/localization-in-angular-application-using-angular-locale/

Comment: Same result, still in the root folder.